# How to write the signature of a method in LaTex?

Tags: code, pseudocode

I'm writing an article in LaTex about programming and I need to write the signature of a C++ method using a specific format, only the statement of the method, not the body.

for example:

```
void cvtColor( InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int code, int dstCn=0 );
```

I would like something like this:

```
void cvtColor( InputArray src, 
               OutputArray dst, 
               int code, 
               int dstCn=0 
              );
```

Thanks.

Comment: This might be possible, but perhaps the `doxygen` way is better to achieve this. Welcome to TeX.SX anyway

Comment: `verbatim` is perhaps what you need ...

Comment: Maybe you can achieve that using the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.

Comment: Thank you very much, we can do this with the three options, they are real solutions, but I finally used listings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways. Here are some options:

- `verbatim`

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}

  \lipsum*[1]
  \begin{verbatim}
  void cvtColor( InputArray src, 
                 OutputArray dst, 
                 int code, 
                 int dstCn=0 
                );
  \end{verbatim}

  \lipsum[2]

  \end{document}
  ```
- [`fancyvrb`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb); more flexibility than a regular `verbatim` environment.

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{fancyvrb,lipsum}

  \begin{document}

  \lipsum*[1]
  \begin{Verbatim}
  void cvtColor( InputArray src, 
                 OutputArray dst, 
                 int code, 
                 int dstCn=0 
                );
  \end{Verbatim}

  \lipsum[2]

  \end{document}
  ```
- [`listings`](//ctan.org/pkg/listings); more flexibility with formatting based on language.

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{listings,lipsum}

  \lstset{
    language = C++,
    basicstyle = \ttfamily
  }

  \begin{document}

  \lipsum*[1]
  \begin{lstlisting}
  void cvtColor( InputArray src, 
                 OutputArray dst, 
                 int code, 
                 int dstCn=0 
                );
  \end{lstlisting}

  \lipsum[2]

  \end{document}
  ```